# Reparent in TFS vs recreating the branch

Tags: tfs, branch, branching-and-merging, tfvc

We have the following branch structure

Dev > 2017

Where all changes go from Dev to 2017 Release, we would like to create the 2018 release branch so we branch off 2017

Dev > 2017 > 2018

We would like to reparent Dev to 2018

Dev > 2018

In the past we would do a baseless merge from 2018 into Dev checkin the changes and reparent this has worked fine in the past.

The question i have is if after creating the 2018 branch. If i delete the Dev branch and then create a new branch from 2018 called Dev are there any disadvantages to this ?

I have done this it seems to work but do not know of any implications of doing this way.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your scenario, it seems that you don't need the branch "2017" any more and you only have 2 branches before, so there's no effect on your files/items under the branches. The impact is the history/changesets of the old Dev branch will lose.